# Incremetal backup using mysqldump in MySQL

Tags: mysql, backup

I wanted to take an incremental backup using `mysqldump` for a MySQL database. I have created a script and had taken backup using crontab. It took backup but not incremental; it only takes a full database backup. I didn't find any way to take incremental backup.

My code is given below:

## backup.sh Script

```
#!/bin/bash
YEAR=$(date +%Y)
MONTH=$(date +%m)
DAY=$(date +%d)
HOUR=$(date +%H)
mkdir -p $YEAR/$MONTH/$DAY/$HOUR
mysqldump -uroot -pRedhat@123 mydb > $YEAR/$MONTH/$DAY/$HOUR/backup.sql
```

## Crontab

```
crontab -e
# Minute   Hour   Day of Month       Month          Day of Week        Command
# (0-59)  (0-23)     (1-31)    (1-12 or Jan-Dec)  (0-6 or Sun-Sat)
30        *         *            *                1-6       exec  '/bin/bash /home/backup.sh'
```

## Backup Files Listing

```
bash backup.sh

[root@master 17]# ls -lh backup.sql 
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 49M Jun 15 17:05 backup.sql

[root@master 17]# ls -lh backup.sql 
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 362M Jun 18 17:23 backup.sql
```

I want that it will take only changed blocks backup not full backup like above example.

#### Additional Information

I am using the free version of MySQL. No enterprise features available.

Comment: You might want to consider adding as much details as possible to your question to prevent "wrong" answers. Can you think of anything else that might be relevant, but which you have not yet included in your question? (e.g. MySQL version, additional scripts, ...) Click on [edit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/210005/edit) to modify your question if required.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in my previous answer, `mysqldump` does not provide incremental backup/dump capabilities:

> The mysqldump client utility performs logical backups, producing a set of SQL statements that can be executed to reproduce the original database object definitions and table data. It dumps one or more MySQL databases for backup or transfer to another SQL server. The mysqldump command can also generate output in CSV, other delimited text, or XML format.

<sup>***Reference:*** [4.5.4 mysqldump — A Database Backup Program](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#mysqldump-option-summary) (MySQL Documentation)</sup>

`mysqldump` doesn't contain any option(s) that would allow you to perform an incremental **dump**.

<sup>***Reference:*** [Option Syntax - Alphabetical Summary](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#mysqldump-option-summary) (MySQL Documentation)</sup>

## Solution

To have an incremental backup without being able to use the `mysqlbackup` program you would have to perform the following task.

### Physical (Raw) Backup

You can perform a backup of the MySQL `\data` directory to have a current backup of the databases in your MySQL instance. It is recommended to close/shutdown the instance to have a consistent state:

> Backups can be performed while the MySQL server is not running. **If the server is running, it is necessary to perform appropriate locking so that the server does not change database contents during the backup.**

<sup>*(**emphasis** mine)*</sup>
<sup>***Reference:***  [7.1 Backup and Recovery Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/backup-types.html) (MySQL Documentation)</sup>

### Incremental Binary Log Backup

> MySQL supports incremental backups: You must start the server with the --log-bin option to enable binary logging; see [Section 5.4.4, “The Binary Log”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-log.html). The binary log files provide you with the information you need to replicate changes to the database that are made subsequent to the point at which you performed a backup. At the moment you want to make an incremental backup (containing all changes that happened since the last full or incremental backup), you should rotate the binary log by using FLUSH LOGS. This done, you need to copy to the backup location all binary logs which range from the one of the moment of the last full or incremental backup to the last but one. These binary logs are the incremental backup; at restore time, you apply them as explained in [Section 7.5, “Point-in-Time (Incremental) Recovery Using the Binary Log”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/point-in-time-recovery.html). The next time you do a full backup, you should also rotate the binary log using [`FLUSH LOGS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flush.html#flush-logs) or [mysqldump --flush-logs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html). See [Section 4.5.4, “mysqldump — A Database Backup Program”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html).

<sup>***Reference:*** [7.2 Database Backup Methods](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/backup-methods.html) (MySQL Documentation)</sup>

`FLUSH LOGS`

> Closes and reopens any log file to which the server is writing. If binary logging is enabled, the sequence number of the binary log file is incremented by one relative to the previous file. If relay logging is enabled, the sequence number of the relay log file is incremented by one relative to the previous file.

<sup>***Reference:*** [`FLUSH LOGS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flush.html#flush-logs)</sup>

## An Example:

1. Once a week at 8pm:
    a. Create a copy of the MySQL `/data` directory while the database is down.
    b. After "FULL" Backup: Restart the database.
2. Every other day at 8pm:
    a. execute a `FLUSH LOGS` command
    b. create a backup copy of the binary logs directory

You can further optimise the incremental backup by storing the name of the last n-1 binary log file as an additional flag-file and starting off from there. That depends on your requirements.

---

> **DISCLAIMER**
>   Please test your backup and restore procedure before you implement this in a productive environment. No guarantee given that this procedure will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

`mysqldump` is a utility for creating a logical full backup. That tool does not allow you to make incremental backups, but it is needed to tune incremental backups.

#### MySQL incremental backups based on binlogs

Binary logs are a set of log files that contain information about all changes made to a MySQL database. With this data, you can restore the data in a database to an earlier date.

As a rule, binlogs do not contain all the data from the moment the database was created. The starting point for restoring from binlogs is a **FULL** backup created via `mysqldump`.

*i.e. A full backup creation is a very first step in the creation of incremental backups.*

```
mysqldump --flush-log --master-data=2 [other options]
```

`--flush-log` - initializes writing to a new binlog file

`--master-data=2` - writes the name of a new binlog file to a .sql dump (it will be the first in the restore chain)

If you do not use replication, the `--delete-master-log` [option](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_delete-master-logs) may also be useful. It will remove the binary logs that were created before the FULL backup.

An incremental backup is simply copying new binlog files to an archive and sending them to a destination.

As a rule, the storage directory for binlog files is located by the following path:

In Linux `/opt/mysql/data`

In Windows `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\Data\`

The main difficulty is that you need to copy only new files, and not copy the last binlog file. Anyway, it can be done, here are more details on how to do it [on Windows](https://blog.sqlbackupandftp.com/mysql-incremental-backups-on-windows) and [on Linux](https://blog.sqlbak.com/incremental-mysql-server-backup-via-binary-log).

#### Restore from the binlogs

First, you need to restore a FULL backup

```
mysql [connection settings] < full.sql
```

Then you need to restore all the binlog files that were created after the full backup was created. The number of the first binlog file can be found in the full backup, there will be a line similar to this:

> -- CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.002927', MASTER_LOG_POS=120;

You need to convert binlog files to SQL instructions. This can be done using the `mysqlbinlog` utility. It takes a list of binlog files as input, note - order matters:

```
mysqlbinlog mysql-bin.002927 mysql-bin.002928 mysql-bin.002929 mysql-bin.002930 > inc.sql
```

Now you can restore incremental backups:

```
mysql [connection settings] < inc.sql
```

##### Additional information

1. If you prefer to use binlogs for backups then it is better to set the [ROW format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/binlog-formats.html) for binlogs
2. [MySQL incremental backups can be performed via the Percona XtraBackup utility](https://docs.percona.com/percona-xtrabackup/8.0/backup_scenarios/incremental_backup.html)
3. [MySQL Enterprise backup - also supports incremental backups](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-enterprise-backup/4.1/en/mysqlbackup.incremental.html)